# Are $40\times 10^n-31$ (for even $n\geq4$) or $48\times 10^n-39$ (for $n\geq4$) possibly perfect squares?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Are these numbers possibly perfect squares? I guess there is no perfect square, but I think it needs a standard number theory proof.

1. $40\times 10^{n}-31$, where $n \geq 4$ and $n$ is even.
2. $48\times 10^{n}-39$, where $n \geq 4$.

If not, please gives a counterexample.

Comment: 1. can be rewritten to $40\times 100^m - 31$ where $m\geq 2$. It is the standard way to handle "$n$ is even"

Comment: 2. We have $9\mid (48\cdot 10^n-39)=x^2$, so that $3\mid x$.

Comment: so? don't think that helps

Comment: If $\exists$ $x=\underbrace{9\cdots9}_{A}69$ such that $\not\exists$ $m$, $m^2\equiv x\pmod{10^{A+2}}$, we're left with finite situations to verify.