# Solving a non-linear recurrence relation

Tags: number-theory, recurrence-relations

First of all, I was looking for the all possible non-negative integers $k$ such that
$$360k^2+1$$
is a perfect square. The problem is some how related to my another question: [Are these numbers perfect squares?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2419972/are-these-numbers-perfect-squares)

After few tries, I notice that the following recurrence relation generates some of the $k$ that I am looking for:
$k_0=0,$ $k_1=1$ and define
$$k_n=2\sqrt{360k_{n-1}^2+1}+k_{n-2}\qquad\forall n \geq 2$$
I found by Excel that, at least for the first 15 terms $k_0,k_1,...,k_{14}$ all make $360k^2+1$ a perfect square. Here is my problem:

1. Prove or disprove that $\lbrace 360k_n^2+1:n \geq 0 \rbrace$ are perfect squares and find the general form of $k_n$.
2. If the statement $1$ is true, does $\lbrace k_n :n \geq 0\rbrace$ collect all the possible non-negative integers $k$ such that $360k^2+1$ are perfect squares?
3. If the statement $1$ is false, then what is the set
   $$\lbrace k\in \lbrace 0 \rbrace \cup \mathbb{N}:360k^2+1 \mbox{ is a perfect square} \rbrace?$$

Comment: What makes you stop at $k_{14}$?

Comment: I checked up to $k_{30}$ which starts to be huge !

Comment: This is a Pell equation with solutions $k=\frac{x^n-y^n}{x-y}$ where $x=19+6 \sqrt{10}$ and $y=19-6 \sqrt{10}$ with $n\geq 1$

Comment: it is way too huge, so I stopped

Comment: @Lozenges Can you please explain more details about it?

Comment: you want to write down all integer solutions of the Pell equation $s^2-360k^2=1$. The minimal solution is $s=19$, $k=1$ and the general solution is given by $k_n=\frac{x^n-y^n}{x-y}$ and $s_n=\frac{x^n+y^n}{2}$ where $x=19+6 \sqrt{10}$ and $y=19-6 \sqrt{10}$

Comment: @YanLai: perhaps a good moment to get in contact with Pari/GP. You can get more data and experiences because it has arbitrary precision computation. You can go up to $k=2080805$ to collect enough examples to derive the recursion-parameters from the empirical data. Then to prove it (per induction) should be not too hard (I didn't try that, I confess)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned , the equation $$m^2=360k^2+1$$ is a so-called Pellequation. A Pell-equation is an equation of the form $$m^2=D\cdot k^2+1$$ where $D$ is a positive integer, not being a perfect square. Every Pell-equation has infinite many solutions. The solution with the smallest positive $k$ ($k=0$ is always a solution, called the "trivial solution") is called the "fundamental solution". In the case of $D=360$ , it is $(19/1)$

The continued fraction of $\sqrt{360}$ is $$[18,1,36,1,36,1,36,\cdots]$$ and the solutions are the denominators of the even convergents. Using the relations for the convergents, you can derive the reccurence-relation for $k_n$.

RESULT :

The positive numbers $k$ , such that $360k^2+1$ is a perfect suqare , form the sequence $k_s$ witrh $k_1=1$ , $k_2=38$ , $$k_{n}=38k_{n-1}-k_{n-2}$$ for $n\ge 3$
After $1$ and $38$ , the next solutions are :

```
1443
54796
2080805
79015794
3000519367
113940720152
4326746846409
164302439443390
6239165952002411
236924003736648228
8996872976040630253
341644249085807301386
12973484592284636822415
492650770257730391950384
18707755785201470257292177
710402069067398139385152342
26976570868775927826378496819
1024399290944417859262997726780
38900196485019102724167535120821
1477183067139781485659103336864418
```

If you prefer a formula for $k_n$ : $$k_n=\frac{a^n-b^n}{\sqrt{1440}}$$

where $a=19+\sqrt{360}$ and $b=19-\sqrt{360}$. This is equal to $\frac{a^n}{\sqrt{1440}}$, correctly rounded to the next integer.

Comment: It is impressive! That encourages me to learn more things about algebraic number theory

Comment: Do the corresponding m have good formula?

Comment: @YanLai They satisfy the same reccurence-relation as the $k's$. Only the starting values are different.

Comment: The formula is $\frac{a^n+b^n}{2}$ with $a,b$ defined as in the answer