# Determine a type of number whether it is a power of 10

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

In [Solving a non-linear recurrence relation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2451310/solving-a-non-linear-recurrence-relation), I was trying to find the $k$ such that $$\sqrt{360k^2+1}$$ is a natural number. And as Peter shown, it is a Pell's equation, and all the possible $k$ can be generated by a certain formula. Now, actually the original question is, is this number $$\sqrt{360k^2+1}\pm 9k$$ possible to be a power of $10$? My conjecture is that the only possible $k$ is $1$ and $$10^1=\sqrt{360\times 1^2+1}-9\times 1.$$ According to Peter's solution, we have that all the possible natural number of the form $\sqrt{360k^2+1}\pm 9k$ is of the form

\begin{align}
&\frac{(19+6\sqrt{10})^n+(19-6\sqrt{10})^n}{2}\pm 9\frac{(19+6\sqrt{10})^n-(19-6\sqrt{10})^n}{12\sqrt{10}}\\\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor} \binom{n}{2j}19^{n-2j}360^{j}\pm 9\sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor (n-1)/2 \rfloor}\binom{n}{2j+1}19^{n-2j-1}360^j.\\\\
\end{align}

Observe that apparently $n$ is necessarily odd if we ask that number to be a power of ten. Otherwise, say $n=2p$, then
\begin{align}
10^m & =\sum_{j=0}^{p} \binom{2p}{2j}361^{p-j}360^{j}\pm 171\sum_{j=0}^{p-1}\binom{2p}{2j+1}361^{p-j-1}360^j\\\\
& \equiv (1)^p\pm (1)(1)^{p-1} (2p)\\\\
& \equiv 2p+1 \vee 1-2p \mod 10,\\\\
\end{align}
which is a contradiction. So, write $n=2p+1$, where $p \in \lbrace 0 \rbrace \cup \mathbb{N}$, then
$$
10^m=19\sum_{j=0}^{p} \binom{2p+1}{2j}361^{p-j}360^{j}\pm 9\sum_{j=0}^{p}\binom{2p+1}{2j+1}361^{p-j}360^j.
$$

Then I stopped here because I don't know what to do next.